# change datetime format to date format in label

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I want to make the format of my datetime to a date only in my asp.net application. Is it possible to do that.

My code is:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label31" Text='<%# Eval("Birthday")%>' Width="150px"></asp:Label>
```

What do I add to my code that code change it to date only? Can I use the tostring function inside the <%# %>??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its something like this  :

```
<asp:label id="Label31" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Birthday", "format specifier") %>' />
```

so your format can be  the way you want it to be.

```
<asp:label id="Label31" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Birthday", "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}") %>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the format of your date in label like this:

```
Label1.Text = YourDateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

> Can I use the tostring function inside the <%# %>??

Yes you can do that like this:

```
<asp:label id="Label31" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Birthday", "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}") %>' />
```

Comment: @cracker:- Yes but I answered earlier!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this..

```
<asp:label id="Label31" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Birthday", "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}") %>' />
```

OR

```
<asp:label id="Label31" runat="server" text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Birthday")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>
```